# Error while installing numpy in venv

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pip

I am getting the following error while trying to install numpy in my venv.  I am running centos.  which python points to the python in my venv directory

```
    (venv)bash-3.2$ pip install numpy
    Downloading/unpacking numpy
      Running setup.py egg_info for package numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib/sse2', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib/sse2', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE      /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1494: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        language = f77

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
        language = f77

    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
      NOT AVAILABLE    /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['lapack']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        language = f77

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
        language = f77

    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -c'
    gcc: _configtest.c
    gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    success!
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -c'
    gcc: _configtest.c
    _configtest.c:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exp'
    gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    _configtest.o: In function `main':
    /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/c
    numpy.core - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h']
    building extension "numpy.core._dotblas" sources
    building extension "numpy.core.umath_tests" sources
    building extension "numpy.core.multiarray_tests" sources
    building extension "numpy.lib._compiled_base" sources
    building extension "numpy.numarray._capi" sources
    building extension "numpy.fft.fftpack_lite" sources
    building extension "numpy.linalg.lapack_lite" sources
      adding 'numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.c' to sources.
      adding 'numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.c' to sources.
    building extension "numpy.random.mtrand" sources
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC

    compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -c'
    gcc: _configtest.c
    gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest
    _configtest
    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest
    building data_files sources
    build_src: building npy-pkg config files

Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
    Running from numpy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib/sse2', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib/sse2', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1494: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        language = f77

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
        language = f77

    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
    numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
      NOT AVAILABLE

    /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      FOUND:
        libraries = ['lapack']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        language = f77

      FOUND:
        libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']
        library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']
        define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]
        language = f77

    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    customize Gnu95FCompiler using config
    C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC   
    compile options: '-DNO_ATLAS_INFO=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/umath -c'
    gcc: numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.c
    gcc: numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.c
    /usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -lblas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':
    (.text+0xa): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':
    (.text+0xa): undefined reference to `MAIN__'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -lblas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so" failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o4oHZQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/include/site/python2.7:
    Running from numpy source directory.

non-existing path in 'numpy/distutils': 'site.cfg'

F2PY Version 2

blas_opt_info:

blas_mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib/sse2', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_blas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64/atlas', '/usr/lib64/sse2', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib/sse2', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1494: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

blas_info:

  FOUND:

    libraries = ['blas']

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']

    language = f77

  FOUND:

    libraries = ['blas']

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']

    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]

    language = f77

lapack_opt_info:

lapack_mkl_info:

mkl_info:

  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib', '/usr/local/lib64', '/usr/local/lib', '/usr/lib64', '/usr/lib']

  NOT AVAILABLE



  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_threads_info:

Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2

  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



atlas_info:

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib64

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/atlas

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64/sse2

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib64

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib64

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib/sse2

  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib

  libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib

numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info

  NOT AVAILABLE



/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/numpy/distutils/system_info.py:1408: UserWarning:

    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.

    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the

    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting

    the ATLAS environment variable.

  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)

lapack_info:

  FOUND:

    libraries = ['lapack']

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']

    language = f77

  FOUND:

    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas']

    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64']

    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1)]

    language = f77

running install

running build

running config_cc

unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options

running config_fc

unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options

running build_src

build_src

building py_modules sources

building library "npymath" sources

customize Gnu95FCompiler

Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran

customize Gnu95FCompiler

customize Gnu95FCompiler using config

C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC



compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -c'

gcc: _configtest.c

gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest

success!

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest

C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC
compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -c'

gcc: _configtest.c

_configtest.c:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exp'

gcc -pthread _configtest.o -o _configtest

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

_configtest.o: In function `main':

/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/_configtest.c:6: undefined reference to `exp'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

failure.

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o

C compiler: gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include -fPIC -fPIC
compile options: '-Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -Inumpy/core/include -I/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/include/python2.7 -c'

gcc: _configtest.c

_configtest.c:1: warning: conflicting types for built-in function 'exp'

gcc -pthread _configtest.o -lm -o _configtest

success!

removing: _configtest.c _configtest.o _configtest

building library "npysort" sources

building extension "numpy.core._dummy" sources

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h' to sources.

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h' to sources.

executing numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h' to sources.

numpy.core - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h']
  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h' to sources.

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h' to sources.

executing numpy/core/code_generators/generate_numpy_api.py

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h' to sources.

executing numpy/core/code_generators/generate_ufunc_api.py

  adding 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h' to sources.

numpy.core - nothing done with h_files = ['build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/config.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/_numpyconfig.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h', 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h']

building extension "numpy.core._dotblas" sources

building extension "numpy.core.umath_tests" sources

building extension "numpy.core.multiarray_tests" sources

building extension "numpy.lib._compiled_base" sources

building extension "numpy.numarray._capi" sources

building extension "numpy.fft.fftpack_lite" sources

/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -lblas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':

(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `MAIN__'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/libgfortranbegin.a(fmain.o): In function `main':

(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `MAIN__'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib64 -L/nlu/users/indrani_gorti/prefix/lib -Lbuild/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7 -llapack -lblas -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.so" failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o4oHZQ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /nrg5/nlu/data/users/indrani_gorti/venv/venv/build/numpy
Storing complete log in /home/indrani_gorti/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: also add the log stored if that's different for some reason

Comment: Hi, I figured out the problem.  CFLAGS AND LDFLAGS have to be unset.  Then pip install numpy works.

Comment: yeah you were trying to link non existent libraries imho, I was just wondering if it said that more explicitly in the log

Comment: You should post it your answer as an answer and accept this answer. Iy might be helpful for other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CFLAGS AND LDFLAGS in your bashrc file have to be unset. Then pip install numpy works.